# Why I still got NetworkOnMainThreadException in spite of using @WorkerThread annotation?

Tags: java, android, networkonmainthread

I'm calling `sendPhoneNumberHandler` from `@OnClick` which mean normal to get `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.
To handle this problem I used `@WorkerThread` annotation that allow the method call to run outside the UI/Main Thread. In contrast I still got `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

```
  @WorkerThread
  public void sendPhoneNumberHandler(final Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    MonoApplication application = MonolApplication.get(phoneNumberMvpView.getContext());
    rx.Observable<HeaderResponse> checkPhoneNumber =
        application.getMonolService(Constants.monolAPIUrl).checkPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

    subscription = checkPhoneNumber.subscribe(new Observer<HeaderResponse>() {
      @Override public void onCompleted() {
      }

      @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
        phoneNumberMvpView.onPhoneNumberSendResult(false, 0);
      }

      @Override public void onNext(HeaderResponse s) {
        phoneNumberMvpView.onClearText();
        phoneNumberMvpView.onPhoneNumberSendResult(true, s.getError());
      }
    });
  }
```

Any clue ?

Comment: You should put your method inside an AsyncTask.

Comment: I missed to subscribe on IO Thread (`subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the annotation does not make that method run off the UI thread. It simply indicates that this method needs to be executed in a separate thread